# Как Spring DataJpa работает со связанными таблицами?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Есть две сущности со связью ManyToMany: `Student` и `Course`. У студента может быть несколько курсов, а один курс может проходить несколько студентов. Эту связь я отображаю в такой таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE students_courses
(
    student_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    course_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT student_course_idx UNIQUE (student_id, course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES courses (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Сущность `Student`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "students_courses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
    List<Course> courses;
    // другие поля
}
```

Сущность `Course`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    List<Student> students;
    // другие поля
}
```

Работа с базой данных идёт через Spring DataJpa. Я использую имплементацию JpaRepository, которая принимает сущности и автоматически обновляет/удаляет/сохраняет. Например, вот репозиторий для курса *(для студента такой же, только называется CrudStudentRepository)*:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface CrudCourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Integer> {
}
```

---

У сущности Student есть поле `List<Course> courses`. В моём понимании, если попытаться обновить сущность `Student`, передав в `CrudStudentRepository#save()` студента с пустым списком курсов, то в таблице **student_courses** будут удалены все записи, в которых фигурирует обновляемый студент, и это так.

Однако, когда я обновляю сущность Course, у которой свою очередь есть поле `List<Student> students`, то как бы я не менял содержимое списка students перед сохранением сущности в базу, эти изменения никак не отображаются на таблице **student_courses**. Как мне тогда их удалять/обновлять?

По какому принципу JpaRepository обновляет/удаляет/добавляет записи в таблице связей?

Comment: Обратите внимание на `CREATE TABLE student_courses` и `@JoinTable(name = "students_courses"`, у вас имена таблиц разные

Comment: @DmitryD спасибо, исправил. Но это не имеет значения, потому что представленный код - псевдокод для лучшего понимания. В реальности у меня другие сущности и таблицы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Всё кроется в аннотации @JoinTable

Итак, есть две сущности Student и Course, связанные отношением ManyToMany. Это отношение отображается в таблице **students_courses**. И ещё сущность Student содержит список курсов, а сущность Course, соответственно, содержит список студентов. Так почему же список курсов в Student может влиять на записи **students_courses**, а список студентов в Course никак на неё них не влияет?

Причина кроется в аннотации `@JoinTable`. А именно - в её расположении.

Несмотря на то, что отношение ManyToMany в моём понимании предполагает равенство сущностей, в реальности это не совсем так. Сущность, в которой список аннотирован `@JoinTable` является ведущей. То есть именно она определяет записи в таблице связей *(таблица students_courses в нашем случае)*, а связанная сущность никак на эту таблицу не влияет.

На [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) владелец аннотации определяется как "владелец отношения". А вот что написано в официальной документации в `@JoinTable`:

> When a join table is used in mapping a relationship with an embeddable
> class on the owning side of the relationship, the containing entity
> rather than the embeddable class is considered the owner of the
> relationship.

*перевод:*

> Когда объединяемая таблица используется для сопоставления отношения с
> встраиваемым классом на стороне-владельце отношения, владельцем
> отношения считается содержащая сущность, а не встраиваемый класс.

Из чего я также делаю вывод о том, что мой ответ верен.

---

Может возникануть вопрос: а что, если мы хотим управлять записями в таблице связей со стороны обеих сущностей?

Самым очевидным решением для меня было расположить `@JoinTable` в обеих сущностях, и это действительно сработало. Я не знаю, насколько это корректное решение, потому что есть и другие варианты *(на том же Baeldung)*, но это действительно работает.

---

Таким образом решение конкретно моей проблемы следующее. Если я хочу, чтобы обновление сущности Course влияло на таблицу связей, я просто должен сделать вот так:

**Student**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
    List<Course> courses;
    // другие поля
}
```

**Course**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "students_courses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    )
    List<Student> students;
    // другие поля
}
```

А если необходимо, чтобы на таблицу связей влияли обе сущности, то лучше рассмотреть другой вариант, например вот [этот](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many#2-creating-a-composite-key-in-jpa).