# Связь ManyToOne запутался совсем

Tags: java, sql, spring

Я только пробую работать с БД, поэтому сильно не ругайтесь.

У меня есть БД, в одной таблице описаны студенты, во второй их группы, причем студент может находиться ни в одной из групп, а может быть сразу в нескольких :

```
group {
id,
name
}
student {
id, 
name,
group_id 
}
```

Создал две сущности :

```
GroupEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "groupEntity")
    private List<StudentEntity> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
}

StudentEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private GroupEntity groupEntity;    
}
```

И тут я понял, что что-то не так.
По моей структуре БД студент может быть только в одной группе, а сущности вроде как я создал правильно.
Как мне исправить структуру БД?

И правильно ли я описал связи таблиц в сущностях?

Вот тут есть пример: [Примеры записи аннотаций @OneToMany @OneToOne @ManyToMany](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993198/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-onetomany-onetoone-manytomany-manytoone-hibernate/993199#993199)
Одни в один мой пример : у поста может быть много комментариев (@OneToMany).
Как они это реализовали с помощью двух таблиц в БД? И обошлись без ManyToMany.

Comment: *причем студент может находиться ни в одной из групп, а может быть сразу в нескольких* Тогда это ни фига не OneToMany. Это чистое ManyToMany, которое решается через связующую таблицу.

Comment: Не понял, что нужно: нужно, чтобы студент принадлежал только одной группе или к нескольким?

Comment: три возможных варианта :ни в одной из групп, в одной, или сразу в нескольких. Скорее всего Akina прав, тут должно быть ManyToMany

Comment: Продублирую сюда, потому не уверен, что вы получили нотификацию... Я прочитал ответ по вашей ссылке, но не нашёл там момента, где oneToMany используется в качестве ManyToMany. Если вы про тот пример, где профессор и студенты, то это обычное OneToMany, студент может относиться только к одному профессору, а к профессору относится несколько студентов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в данном случае ManyToMany. Необходимо аннотировать классы следующим образом:

```
GroupEntity {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupEntities")
    private Set<StudentEntity> students;
}

StudentEntity {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "student_entities_groups",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_entity_id"),
        inverseJoinColumn = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    )
    private Set<GroupEntity> groupEntities;    
}
```

Вам потребуется три таблицы для такой связи. Одна для студентов, вторая для групп, а третья будет соединять их. Этой таблицей в данном случае является `student_entities_groups`. Эта таблица будет содержать две колонки: id студента и id группы *(обратите внимание, что у записей в таблице связей не будет собственных id, только FK на связываемые сущности)*.

При работе с сущностями, участвующими в отношениях ManyToMany, могут возникать некоторые интересные моменты. Подробнее об этом в моём [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1233668/385867) к другому вопросу. Если в двух словах, то несмотря на то, что в ManyToMany формально обе сущности имеют одинаковые права в отношении друг-друга, фактически владельцем связи является та сущность, в которой находится аннотация `@JoinTable`.

Comment: @alexSerg я прочитал ответ по вашей ссылке, но не нашёл там момента, где oneToMany используется в качестве ManyToMany. Если вы про тот пример, где профессор и студенты, то это обычное OneToMany, студент может относиться только к одному профессору, а к профессору относится несколько студентов.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста я правильно исправил структуру БД и сущности в соответствии с вашим ответом.

Comment: @alexSerg если в остальных местах ошибок нет, то должно работать. Только зачем вы в student_entities_groups сделали отдельные колонки для fk? group_id и student_id это и есть FK. У вас в итоге должно быть только две колонки. В остальном верно. И откатите свой вопрос именно к состоянию вопроса, т.к. вопросы не предназначены для уточнения. Задавайте уточнения в комментариях.

Comment: Я просто посмотрел ваш вопрос, на который вы ссылку кинули и там тоже в связной таблице сначала ключи указаны а потом fk для них

Comment: @alexSerg это просто синтаксис в PostgreSQL такой. FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id) ON DELETE CASCADE - сначала пишу FOREIGN KEY, потом его указываю в скобках, а потом пишу, куда он ссылается и на какую колонку

Comment: но я так понимаю .что эта строка создает поле student_id  в таблице
CREATE TABLE students_courses
(
    student_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ...
);
а вот тут уже создается сам  FOREIGN KEY:
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,

Comment: @alexSerg ну да. Как бы в строке, которая начинается с FOREIGN KEY происходит маппинг колонки на стороннюю колонку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120452/discussion-between-alex-serg-and-zhenyria).